# No Function to Pointer Decay during Assignment

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-pointers

In the below given code snippet, when i wrote `f = A;` then **why doesn't `A` decay** to a pointer to a function?

```
//Func is alias for "pointer to a function that returns an int and does not take any parameter"
typedef int (*Func)();

int A(){
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    Func* f = &A;//cannot convert ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int (**)()’ in initialization - I UNDERSTAND THIS ERROR
   
   
    f = A;//error: cannot convert ‘int()’ to ‘int (**)()’ in assignment - My QUESTION IS THAT IN THIS CASE WHY DOESN'T "A" decay to a pointer to a function and give the same error as the above 
    
}
```

I know why `Func *f = &A;` produces error. But i expected `f = A;` to produce the same error because i thought in this case `A` will decay to a pointer to a function and hence should produce the same error as `Func*f = &A;`. To be precise, i thought i would get the error

```
error: cannot convert ‘int(*)()’ to ‘int (**)()’ in assignment
```

But to my surprise, there is no decay and i do not get the above error.

Why/How is this so? That is, why is there no decay.

Comment: Got it. Misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't A decay to a pointer to a function?

The error message says that a function (`int()`) cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to a pointer to a function (`int (**)()`), because the type of the expression (`A`) is a function.

The function would decay if there was a valid conversion sequence to the target type through the decayed type. But there isn't such conversion sequence, and so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Ok can you point out from the Standard where it says something like, "function to pointer decay will happen only if there is a valid conversion sequence". I want to know(in which situations) when decay is allowed.

Comment: So this means, because even if there was a decay there will be mismatch of types on the rhs and lhs and so this couldn't work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AanchalSharma In general, there simply aren't conversions that just happen for no reason. The standard doesn't say that the function name will be converted, but that the function name *can* be implicitly converted.

Comment: So is it correct to say that, *"even if there was a decay it wouldn't have mattered because the type of the left hand side and the resulting decayed type on the right hand side would still mismatch."*  So, the compiler gives error that it cannot convert `int()` to `int(**)()`.